# How does pricing on the Amazon River boats work?

Tags: tickets, brazil, riverboats, amazon-river

Last week I went from Manaus to Santarém by boat. I bought my ticket in the Manaus port, from a guy standing around the entrance (he looked shady but the Tourist Police told me he's an authorized seller). I paid R$90, I travelled sleeping in a hammock, without a cabin. A girl sleeping next to me paid R$80.
On the boat I saw this list, saying the price of Manaus-Santarém is R$180:
[image: list of prices on the boat]

Then I'm planning to go further to Belém, someone told me before the price is R$150, but the only agency I found says it's R $200 and that it's a promotion. There's no price neither in the agency nor on the ticket I had from Manaus.

Is there some official pricing list for these boats that I can reference when buying the next ticket? I'd treat the one on the boat as the official one, but I'm confused why I paid half the price.

Comment: FWIW, I also remember the second leg being more expensive. I also think that the listed 'official' rates for boats on the Amazon are about as reliable as published airline fares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, any board, if not written with chalk or easily editable, is outdated.

I have found this site with prices (in Portuguese):
[Porto de Manaus Agency](https://www.portodemanaus.com.br/?pagina=preco-de-passagens&pg=2)

Also there's this trip's tips site describing the travel (in Portuguese):
[Viaje na viajem](https://www.viajenaviagem.com/2012/10/santarem-manaus-de-barco)

You can compare those prices with a regular airliners prices (in Portuguese):
[Decolar.com](https://www.decolar.com/passagens-aereas/mao/stm/passagens-aereas-para-santarem-saindo-de-manaus?from=SB&searchType=ONEWAY)

Note getting back by the river is not (necessarily) the same price because the river flows from Manaus to Santarém so Manaus-Santarém is a 30h trip while Santarém-Manaus is a 42h trip.

The Belém leg is longer, so you should expect prices not to be the same.
[Google maps Manaus-Santarém-Belém by road](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/Manaus,+Amazonas/Santar%C3%A9m,+PA/Bel%C3%A9m,+PA/@-4.6725805,-60.2941806,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m24!4m23!1m5!1m1!1s0x926c1bc8b37647b7:0x2b485c9ff765a9cc!2m2!1d-60.0217314!2d-3.1190275!1m5!1m1!1s0x9288f9213cb04ad5:0x80be3f9dd767d647!2m2!1d-54.7009228!2d-2.4506291!1m5!1m1!1s0x92a461af84756ce1:0x570d540215864c35!2m2!1d-48.4901799!2d-1.4557549!2m2!1b1!3b1!3e0!4e1)

I was not able to find an updated site with prices, but I did find some blogs about the Santarém-Belém leg.

(all in Portuguese)

http://www.verdejava.com.br/lugares/rio-amazonas-de-santarem-a-belem/
http://meusegundolar.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/viagem-santarem-belem-de-barco.html
http://guiaviajarmelhor.com.br/rota-dos-rios-viagem-de-barco-belem-x-santarem-x-manaus/

If you seek adventure and to blend with the locals it will be a nice trip. Personaly I cannot do that unless by a regular airline because of the (lack of) comfort and time.

And finally, please remember "Couples no allowed in the same hammock" =)
[image: Finally remember "Couples no allowed in the same hammock"]